# Issues when passing a $_POST value into function

Tags: php, mongodb, post

I have a problem when I pass a value to a function that is post into the document in PHP

This is the function definition,

```
function findstation($val){
   global $positions_table;
   var_dump($val);
   $id=$val;
   $query = array('uid'=> $id );
   $result = $positions_table->find($query);
   foreach ($result as $station){
      return $station['name'];
   }
}
```

This function queries a mongoDB database to find and return the key **name** from the DB
I have page which posts the **id** into the document as `$_POST['id']`.

This is how I search in it

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "START!";
    $st = $_POST['station'];
    var_dump($t);
    findstation($st);
    echo "EXECUTED THE FUNCTION"; // Just added this to diagnose
}
```

When I search like this, i don't get any results it just displays `START!EXECUTED THE FUNCTION`

But when i call the function like this

```
findstation(2);
```

I get a result. How can I get this to work when I pass it as a varible ?

PS: `$_POST['id']` is passed as value of a `<select>` input.

Comment: I read `global` and skipped to the comments.

Comment: Is it an issue that the echo at the start isn't closed off properly? It starts with a double quote and is finished with a single quote.

Comment: sorry that was a typo here.. Its fine in the code

Comment: Assuming your code is correct, I wonder why your var_dump() does not produce output - at least a notice because of undefined variable $t should be there. On the other hand: You do the search, but do not echo anything. Additionally, you loop with foreach, but exit the function on the first result. No further findings will be accessed...

Comment: it just has 1 record . Just 1 id for each record. Is there any other way to get around this rather than using the foreach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "START!'; // < == there you use a double to start string and a single quote to end
    $st = $_POST['station'];
    $t = (int)$st;
    var_dump($t);
    findstation($st);
    echo "EXECUTED THE FUNCTION"; // Just added this to diagnose
}
```

Correct:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "START!"; // corrected string;
    $st = $_POST['station'];
    $t = (int)$st;
    var_dump($t);
    findstation($st);
    echo "EXECUTED THE FUNCTION"; // Just added this to diagnose
}
```